# Flutter limit number of items in Hive Box

Tags: flutter, hive, limit, favorites

In my recipe app a user can save a recipe to his/her favorites. This works by adding the recipe to a hive box when the user saves the recipe to favorites. The plan is to limit the number of favorites to 10 in a free version. In the paid version there will be the limit of 30 recipes. How can I do it with hive box?

Answer (score 0):

There is no code so I do not know what type of code you have written. But I can explain the logic below and you can work your way ahead.

Retrieve all Fav recipes present in the hive in the form of a list.

```
if(hiveRecipeList.length < 10){
 addRecipeToHive();
}else{
 upgradeToPro()
}
```